# Error while parse an XML with cyrillic serbian chars anda save into DB

Tags: java, xml, oracle, cyrillic

I've a complex XML file and I've to parse it with Java to get some text inside some tags.
This is done correctly, but there are some rows with cyrillic characters (serbian) and in XML appear in correct mode, when I get it with Java in another one, and when I save it into Oracle, in another one!
How I can elaborate and save this kind of data in the correct cyrillic format from xml to oracle? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure the encodings you use for parsing/storing are ok

Comment: How I can do that? I get the text as simple string...

Answer (score 1):

First: read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Second: you don't get a "simple string", you have a file. Which contains bytes. That **given an encoding** represent a string. When you read it in as a string, you **need** to specify that encoding or things will get corrupted.

Once you have a java.lang.String, it is an actual unicode representation and encoding-independent but when you want to push that string to a database, you once again need to think about encoding because at some point somewhere, the database will have to transform that string to bytes to store it.

Additionally: never "trust" an editor when it comes to examining encoding issues. They almost always have automagic stuff to make stuff work so something that "looks fine" might actually be corrupt or only valid given the assumptions that that specific editor made.